# AntD edatepicker : How to set optional date and null when not chosen

Tags: typescript, datepicker, antd

I am trying to do an application where I user can either choose an end date or leave it empty this is supposed to send a null when end date was not chosen however it return today's date when date is not chosen.

```
              <Form.Item name="startDate" 
                rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select a start date' }]}
              >
                <DatePicker 
                  disabledDate={function(date) : boolean { 
                    return date.isBefore(moment(), 'day');
                  }} 
                  onChange={function(date){ tenancyStartDate = date; }}
                  placeholder="Start Date" 
                />
              </Form.Item>


              <Form.Item name="endDate">
                <DatePicker 
                  placeholder="End Date"
                  disabledDate={function(date) : boolean { 
                    return date.isSameOrBefore(tenancyStartDate, 'day');
                  }} 
                  onChange={function(date){ tenancyEndDate = date; }}
                   
                />
              </Form.Item>
```

How can I pass a null if the end date was not chosen?

Comment: Did you find anything that worked?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly how your `tenancyStartDate` and `tenancyEndDate` are declared and what they hold by default, but this might be giving you issues.

The date picker does send null when the 'x' is pressed to clear the field, but if the value hasn't changed, then whatever default was there will remain stored in your vars.

To fix this, I'd just use `useState` like in [this exmaple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rwghvb).

btw, any reason you're not using a RangePicker instead?

Sample Code

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    tenancyStartDate: moment(),
    tenancyEndDate: undefined,
  });

  function onChange(momentDate, param) {
    console.log({momentDate, param, state});
    // dynamically set your param in state
    setState({...state, ...{[param]: momentDate}});
  }

  return <React.Fragment>
    <Form.Item name="startDate" 
      rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please select a start date' }]}
    >
      <DatePicker 
        disabledDate={function(date) { 
          return date.isBefore(state.tenancyStartDate, 'day');
        }} 
        onChange={(value) => onChange(value, 'tenancyStartDate')}
        placeholder="Start Date" 
      />
    </Form.Item>


    <Form.Item name="endDate">
      <DatePicker 
        placeholder="End Date"
        disabledDate={function(date) { 
          return date.isSameOrBefore(state.tenancyStartDate, 'day');
        }} 
        onChange={(value) => onChange(value, 'tenancyEndDate')}
          
      />
    </Form.Item>
  </React.Fragment>
}
```